# std composed with rolling and shift is not working on pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

Consider the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Amount'] = [13,17,31,48]
```

I want to calculate for each row the std of the previous 2 values of the column "Amount". For example:

- For the third row, the value should be the std of 17 and 13 (which is 2).
- For the fourth row, the value should be the std of 31 and 17 (which is 7).

This is what I did:

```
df['std previous 2 weeks'] = df['Amount'].shift(1).rolling(2).std()
```

But this is not working. I thought that my problem was an index problem. But this works perfectly with the sum method.

```
df['total amount of previous 2 weeks'] = df['Amount'].shift(1).rolling(2).sum()
```

PD : I know that this can be done in some other ways but I want to know the reason for why this does not work (and how to fix it).

Comment: Please do not use images of code/data. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `shift` after `rolling.std`. Also the degrees of freedom is 1 by default, it seems you want it to be 0.

```
df['Stdev'] = df['Amount'].rolling(2).std(ddof=0).shift()
```

Output:

```
   Amount  Stdev
0      13    NaN
1      17    NaN
2      31    2.0
3      48    7.0
```